# Rails.application.secrets.KEY_NAME returns Uninitiated Constant (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to access an API and cannot get the key in secrets.yml to authorize.

I have gone into rails console and confirmed that Rails.application.secrets.KEY_NAME returns the correct key. But it isn't working when I run the .rb file.

How can I get it to work the way it's supposed to?

Comment: `But it isn't working when I run the .rb file` what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that I get an error when running the file that is meant to access the API.

Comment: Restart the rails server and you'll be good.

Comment: How are you running that file? If it's a script running separately from the rest of your app, run it with `rails runner path/to/script.rb` to ensure your environment is loaded first.

Comment: Ah! I was running it as a ruby file. That's where my mistake was. I'll have to rewrite this then, possibly as a rake task.